# Lithium ion battery charging problem

Tags: diodes, overheat

I am making a rechargeable led light 
My power source is mobile litium ion battery, (3.7)v 1800mah
Whenever is use to chrge this battery with the mobile charger 5v...
The diode in4007 connected to the positive terminal of the battery its get as heated that it can melt the soldering... I don't know why it's happening I have changed several diode & the same problem is repeating time & again.... 
And one thing I have noticed that when I have connected a 2ohm resistor in the series the diode temperature is constant & when without of resistor it's get melt...
Why it is happening plzz anyone reading this then plzz ans ur opinion 
One more thing when the battery gets charged more then half then while chrging that battery with the only single diode without resistor in series the the battery charges properly & the diode temperature also be in constant...
Ans plzz guys

Comment: Add a schematic diagram of what you've done, and edit & format your question so that it's not hard to read.

Comment: please stop using "text messaging" words ....  it is annoying that you could not be bothered to type in the full words ..... `plzz`, `ans`, `ur` and `chrge` are not english words and they have no place in a technical question

Comment: the diode gets "melt" because of the large current flowing through it. Diodes have power ratings, and I don't even think a 2 ohm is large enough, despite the fact the re-charging approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

You **can not** use a diode in series with a 5V supply to charge a lithium ion battery! This is very dangerous. You may cause a serious fire if you continue.

You need a proper charger for the battery. The charger **must** limit the charging current to a safe level, and **must** limit the maximum charging voltage. Consult the data sheet for the battery to see what these levels are for the particular battery you are using.

Comment: To add to this, while OP may have used a diode to "drop" the voltage by 0.7V to 4.3V, it still is not safe to use. Chargers often output 4.2V off load (which may have caused them confusion) - but when its charging, its actually 3.7V. A charger is advised, to limit current, give the right voltage, and other battery protection features.

Answer (score 2):

Charging Lithium Ion batteries is much more complicated than just connecting a voltage source and waiting

sure you did some research of your own but my best bet if you want to go DIY try something like this:

https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Lithium-ion-Battery-Charger/

and for some better reading go to battery university https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

But please before you just try something that you think might work you should know that you can cause serious damage to you and those around you if not handling li-ion batteries correctly they are like mini bombs when charging them wrong

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMy2_qNO2Y0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnZuMfq6kec

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT use just a diode. That is asking for disaster, whether it blows the battery or just wastes energy - it will degrade it faster and is not an ideal solution by any metric. Use a specialised charging circuit, like the common TP4056 - they are cheap, and protect your battery from over charging, too much current, and also let you know when its done. Some TP4056 models even have their own OUTPUT pins - so it stops supplying power with too low battery charge - protecting the battery. 5V goes into these types of circuits, and it charges using the right 3.7v, changing currently automatically so it charges correctly.

Here is an image example (that i found on Google) of how you would wire it up. You can still use your 5V source, and the battery is now charging correctly and protected. This specific model uses MiniUSB and doesn't have output pins, but if you look for one on AliExpress (where I got mine) you can find different ones to help suit your usecase[image: TP4056]

Reference: https://www.lelong.com.my/tp4056-single-cell-1a-li-ion-battery-charger-module-mini-usb-littlecraft-F1031632-2007-01-Sale-I.htm

On another note, please consider formatting your question properly. I understand you are a new user, but this is a forum and not an email to a friend - if we have time to write detailed and informative answers and comments, then you have time to format it concisely and properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a diode in series with a 5V supply to charge a lithium ion battery! This is very dangerous. You may cause a serious fire if you continue.

Please explain: