# Crude Li-Po Battery Charging. Is it safe?

Tags: voltage, power, batteries, current, amperage

So I have this drone and I want to play with it but there are no chargers for it nor are there cables for this kind of li-po here but I have minimal knowledge with electronics, just enough to make some fun like: Not to connect cables the wrong way, how stuff works, how to run battery powered electronics off a powerbank crudely with a usb cable hooked to the bank and the power cables on the battery ports of the device.

Anyways I looked up the voltage and amps on charging a lipo battery and suggested charging at 4.5V and 1A but my powerbank only charges at 5V and 0.8A or 2.1A

So is this okay or not? Should I continue charging like this? Sure it's not safe and nor does it feel like it when you are near the battery while charging but for a temporary charger is it a good idea and leaving it unatended cause any problems?[image]

Comment: No, this is not safe and it is not OK. You are risking a serious fire and/or explosion. Do not even think about charging a LiPo cell with a 5V supply, never ever ever.

Comment: Stop! Disconnect the cell immediately! Good grief, on a flammable surface as well...

Comment: Battery is disconnected

Comment: Thanks for warning me. I'm still a newbie in electronics.

Comment: Lithium cells should never be connected directly to a voltage source - the voltage and current must be dynamically adjusted as the charge of the battery increases, which is best left to a charging IC. Having it connected to an unregulated current supply, as well as *5V*, is a serious fire and explosion hazard - never ever do this, even if the battery is dead! This is akin to filling a coffee cup with a fire hose full of coffee - its going to go everywhere and you'll end up burnt.

Comment: Are you sure it said to charge it with 4.5V? That's too high for any lithium chemistry I know of.

Comment: How do they sell a drone without a charger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, please, please use a dedicated charging circuit! You have a 5v supply and a 3.7V lithium cell. Just get yourself a TP4056 charging circuit board and be done with it - it's literally that simple.

Now to explain why:

Lithium cells of nominal voltage 3.7V charge upto a max of 4.2 volts, but you'd need to limit the current to the cell the higher you go. You also want to cut off the supply when it's fully charged (that being when the cell tells you it's at 4.2V) A 5V supply can never do this, and by constantly pushing 5V into it, you are waiting for disaster. A [TP4056](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Micro-USB-TP4056-li-ion-li-po-lipo-Battery-Charger-Module-Discharge-Protection/272986428636?hash=item3f8f4254dc:m:mZvOYFXrR8CXcgPDwxGjHyg:rk:1:pf:1&frcectupt=true) will help out with this - the IC will automatically push the right voltage and limit it to the right current, so it charges safely. It will also light the blue LED to let you know it's done, so you can leave it on for however long and it'll be safe (when charged, it will stop supplying power).

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/415606/183172) is my answer on the topic to another question - with a diagram involved too. It's very easy to set up, and the boards are very cheap too. I got a batch of 5 from AliExpress for only £1.50 (including shipping and currency exchange fees).